# problem about making comment line in Vs Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I used to make an uncomment line as a commented one by these hot keys ctrl+/
but I don't know why recently I couldn't do that.
as I try it my line changes from this:

```
 <div class="form-outline mb-4">
```

to this:

[image]

and in fact it doesn't changes to a comment line

anybody know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's more or less XML. `<!-- this is a comment -->`

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct Language Mode file type set? Your image shows that `div` isn't syntax highlighted.

Comment: is your file now a `Django` HTML file

Comment: @rioV8 No, It's only HTML

Comment: @KenY-N the line in the picture is commented

Comment: why do you show an image of the result of the comment operation? does copy/paste not work after commenting?

Comment: @rioV8 no the comment sign runs as a code above there

Comment: what do you mean with `runs as a code`? what does the file look like in vi or notepad++

Comment: @rioV8 it's like what I've share in the picture in the notepad.

Comment: still no clue what: `runs as a code` means

Comment: @rioV8 just suppose here (commenting area) as a terminal. you want to mention your written code but it runs it as a code

Comment: its getting vaguer the more you try to explain. what is a `commenting area` and what has that to do with a terminal, we talk about commenting a line in the editor with `Ctrl+/`, your text looks like HTML, you can't execute/run HTML (ML = Markup Language) it defines the Markup of the text in between tags.

Comment: @rioV8 yeah yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your HTML is selected on the status bar.
[image]

You can change it by, `Ctrl + Shift + P` and then `Change Language Mode`. Set to HTML.

Comment: Or just click on the pointed-to language tag to get directly to the `Change Language Mode` tool.